# I need help to manipulate complex JavaScript Object returned from fire-base

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and JavaScript. I am trying to access data from an array of complex object.

I need to access this Date:'02-01-2018' of each record. I get key but do not know how to access the this date. I have shared my database and returned value in screenshot.

[image: This is the firebase data structure.]

[image: This is the data returned from database which I have converted into an array.]

```js
{
 "dailyPrices": {
  "01-50005": {
   "04-01-2018": {
    "brands": "",
    "editorID": "janeef@janeef.com",
    "name": "dddf",
    "phone": "",
    "place": "errr"
   },
   "09-01-2018": {
    "brandPriceList": [{
     "brandName": "DC",
     "rsp": "400",
     "stock": "21",
     "supplierChange": "hhhh",
     "supplierRegular": "",
     "wsp": "350"
    }, {
     "brandName": "Barti",
     "rsp": "385",
     "stock": "54",
     "supplierChange": "",
     "supplierRegular": "",
     "wsp": "d380"
    }],
    "brands": "",
    "editorID": "janeef@janeef.com",
    "name": "dddf",
    "orderRequirement": {
     "casualRequirements": "",
     "followUpDate": "",
     "followUpRemarks": "",
     "noOfBags": "",
     "prospectiveness": "",
     "scheduledOrderDate": "",
     "scheduledOrderRemarks": "",
     "urgentRequirementRemarks": "",
     "urgentRequirements": ""
    },
    "phone": "",
    "place": "errr"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ordDetailTXT" id="ordDetailTXT" value="dailyPrice">
```

Code

```js
function findOrderDetails(parentKey) 
{
   var returnArr = [];
      var fetchRecord = database.ref(parentKey);
        fetchRecord.on('value', function(snapshot) {
            var item = snapshot.val();
            item.key = snapshot.key; 
            returnArr.push(item);            
    });
}
```

```js
function btnClickedOrdDetails(){
  var parentkey = ("#ordDetailTXT").val();
findOrderDetails(parentKey);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is useful).

Comment: I have update the question. Please see it.

Comment: That helps. But what are `database` and `parentKey`. It's easiest to help if you ensure the code has no external dependencies, e.g. `firebase.database().reference("01-50002")`.

Comment: i have edited the question now... i hope it is clear now. i can not add "01-50002".  because i need to get other records dynamically.

Comment: In your HTML you have `dailyPrice/01-50002`, while your database has `dailyPrices`.

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake... the value is dailyPrices

Comment: OK. I think we're getting close enough that I can answer. I voted to reopen the question. In the meantime, please replace the screenshot with the actual JSON as text. You can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: this the json i am working on

Comment: Since I can't post an answer until the question is reopened: `var item = snapshot.val(); Object.key(item).forEach(function(key) { console.log(key, item[key]); })` This will log `01-50002` and the object under that key. You can keep using `Object.keys(...)` for any level where you don't know the property names of the children.

Comment: i got this.... `snapshot.forEach(function(child) { item.childKey = child.key;}); ` this solved my problem. thank you sir.

Comment: Could you please make a runnable code snippet (e.g. on jsbin.com)? The one provided in the question relies on jQuery thus results in an error: `VM179:2 Uncaught TypeError: "#ordDetailTXT".val is not a function
    at btnClickedOrdDetails (<anonymous>:2:37)
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: i answered to the question. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add your fire-base credentials in firebase.js in-order to work and create database structure accordingly. i can not share fire-base credentials here.**

[here is the working gif](https://gyazo.com/4348842d503d9f221ef849e0ee8db125)

```js
var returnArr = [];  
function LookForDates()
{
 findPrices();
 return false;
}

function findPrices(){
 
 returnArr = [];  
 var database = firebase.database();
 var strtDate = $('#strtDate').val().split('-');
 strtDate = strtDate[2] + '-' + strtDate[1] + '-' + strtDate[0];

 var endDate = $('#endDate').val().split('-');
 endDate = endDate[2] + '-' + endDate[1] + '-' + endDate[0]; 
   
   var fetchDeleted = database.ref('dailyPrices');
   fetchDeleted.on('value', function(snapshot)
    {
      snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot) {
          var item = snapshot.val();
          item.key = snapshot.key;
          item.parentKey = snapshot.key;
           snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                    item.childKey = child.key;
                });
                if(item.childKey >= strtDate && item.childKey <= endDate)
          {
           returnArr.push(item);
          }
      });
    });
   createPricesTable(returnArr);
 }
 function createPricesTable(returnArr)
 {
  $('#DateList')
      .find('option')
      .remove()
      .end()
      .append('<option value="">Select a district</option>')
      .val('whatever');
      returnArr.forEach(function(child) {
                   $('#DateList').append('<option value="'+ child.childKey +'">'+ child.childKey +'</option>');
                });
     }
     function DateSelected(value){
      //perform some functionality
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Maps Website</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ziFidFTgxJXHMDttyPJKDuTlmxJlwbSkojudK/CkRqKDOmeSbN6KLrGdrBQnT2n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.7.5/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&subset=cyrillic">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              
             <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 5px;">
          
                           <div class="col col-sm-6"> <input required="" class="form-control" type="date" id="strtDate" name="Date"></div>
                            <div class="col col-sm-6"><input required="" class="form-control" type="date" id="endDate" name="Date"></div>
                            <div class="col col-sm-5"></div>
                            <div class="col col-sm-5"><br />
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return LookForDates();" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" style="display: block-inline; float: right;" onclick="ratelistExport()" id="ratelistExportBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Export to Excel</button>
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 10px;">
             <select name="DateList" onchange="DateSelected(value)" class="form-control" id="DateList" required></select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JSFidlle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```